# Apache not releasing threads with low volume of requests

Tags: php, apache, tcp, server

On one of our servers, we are running in to a little curious behavior when one of our deployed apps runs an update against our API.  The gist is that it downloads an XML file that, among other things, contains a file list.  It then proceeds to retrieve the files listed.  The files are served by a PHP process that consumes the file ID, looks it up, and reads the file out to the client if the file exists.

Initially, due to low concurrency (we are running at 2, right now) and file size, the files will come in at approximately 1 per second.  However, as the process draws on, our developers are indicating that download times will raise to over 30 seconds per image.

When looking at the Munin charts, the raise in download times coincides with a rise in Apache Processes (and, thus, memory consumption) around the same time.

[image: Apache Processes]

The curious part is, the actual volume of Apache Accesses, over the course of the update, remains very low.

[image: Apache Accesses]

While (unless I am reading this chart wrong) the number of active connections continues to grow.

[image: Firewall Connections]

It seems odd to us that the processes count just keeps rising like this, and it seems like completed connections are not being dropped.  I would assume that as requests were completed, that the connection would terminate, and the Apache worker would be re-used on a subsequent connection.  However it does not look like this is occurring...  Further, you can see that the number of open connections and active Apache processes does not significantly change under "higher" access load conditions.

The script, as it currently stands, amounts to:

```
if (
    $file = File::get($_GET['file_id']) &&
    !$file->is_locked() && $file->has_member_access($current_member)
){
    /* Stuff */

    header('Cache-Control: public');
    header('Last-Modified: ' . $gmt_modify_time );
    header('Content-Length: ' . $file_size);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file_name . '";');
    header('Content-type: ' . $file_type);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');


    @readfile("$file_path") or die("File not found."); 

}
```

So, essentially, this is hit once per second, over a period of time, until the Apache processes stack up to the point that it is hit once every 30 seconds.  The tip of the charts below represent termination of the update, and show that the processes drop off slowly as well...

One last thing, and a bonus question, is "why do connections stay open for so long after they have been, I would guess, closed?"  You can see in `ipconntrack`, a plateau of ~275 connections sticking around until Wednesday.  That plateau is nearly a week long, and coincides with Established Connections through Firewall.

[image: Connections Week]
[image: Firewall Week]

All very curious, and frustrating...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on **[serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/)**

Comment: @l'L'l Does it?  I mean, it is also PHP related.  It is more server-ish due to the fact that I am including Munin charts, but the real thing would be some interplay between PHP and Apache, no?

Comment: I understand the reason, but what is the policy when a question straddles the line? (more a question for Meta, I know)

Comment: It's up to the moderators I think really; you've asked a good question (and it does straddle the line a bit perhaps), although it might be better received on serverfault. If you feel your question is more in regards to programming then I'll gladly remove my close vote... just let me know.

Comment: No, I want to ask it in the best medium for a good response.  SO is my default go-to, and after reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic I determined that the question falls within the exception bounds of Off-Topic #6, as it involves PHP and Apache insofar as serving a PHP request.  That said, SF may be a better medium, and I know I can not cross-post.  I will see if others feel the same and adjust, but at this time, as it is posted, I will leave it until we get majority or a moderator opinion.

Comment: how are you applying load to your server for your tests?

Comment: We aren't formally testing, this has been in production for some time, and has not caused a problem until now (smaller data-sets don't seem to saturate the server the same way).  However, as mentioned in the question, we hit the above script with a concurrency of 2, and get, initially, a complete download once per second, which then climbs to a concurrency of 2 and complete download times of 30 seconds.

Comment: This is not an s3 caching issue, as it does not go away when we re-initiate the download (which would hit locally cached files).  Further, as mentioned, the Established Connections are sticking around even though the downloads are complete.  That's the real question, I think.